# Identify which cell and the type of exception thrown by datagridview in the data error handler of datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Following is the event handler created for handling the datagridview error in vb.net.
i want to identify which cell has thrown the error and to show proper error messages depending upon that.for eg.if user had not input date in correct format in a particular cell of datagridview i want to show a message saying that date is not in correct format.following is the gridview initializing code  and the error handler

```
    Private Sub gridintialize()
    Dim Itemcode As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim pkt As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim loose As New DataGridViewColumn 
    Dim desp As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim type As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim uom As New DataGridViewColumn
    'Dim batch_no As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim expiry_date As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim qty As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim unit_price As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim disc As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim grossamt As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim disc_p As New DataGridViewColumn
    Dim netamt As New DataGridViewColumn

    With Itemcode
        .Name = "Itemcode"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "ITEM CODE"
        .Width = 195
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With

    With desp
        .Name = "desc"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "Description"
        .Width = 300
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With type
        .Name = "type"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "Type"
        .Width = 50
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With uom
        .Name = "uom"
        .ValueType = GetType(String)
        .HeaderText = "UOM"
        .Width = 60
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With expiry_date
        .Name = "expiry"
        .ValueType = GetType(Date)
        .HeaderText = "Expiry"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With qty
        .Name = "qty"
        .ValueType = GetType(Integer)
        .HeaderText = "Qty"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With unit_price
        .Name = "unitp"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Unit Price"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With disc
        .Name = "disc"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Discount"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With

    With disc_p
        .Name = "discp"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Disc(%)"
        .Width = 70
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    End With
    With grossamt
        .Name = "gamt"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Gross Amount"
        .Width = 70
        .ReadOnly = True
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With netamt
        .Name = "namt"
        .ValueType = GetType(Double)
        .HeaderText = "Net Amount"
        .Width = 80
        .ReadOnly = True
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With pkt
        .Name = "pkt"
        .HeaderText = "PKT"
        .Width = 45
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    End With
    With loose
        .Name = "loose"
        .HeaderText = "Loose"
        .Width = 45
        .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    End With
    With dgsalesitem
        .Columns.Add(pkt)
        .Columns.Add(loose)
        .Columns.Add(Itemcode)
        .Columns.Add(desp)
        .Columns.Add(type)
        .Columns.Add(uom)
        .Columns.Add(expiry_date)
        .Columns.Add(qty)
        .Columns.Add(unit_price)
        .Columns.Add(grossamt)
        .Columns.Add(disc_p)
        .Columns.Add(disc)
        .Columns.Add(netamt)





    End With
End Sub

Private Sub dgsalesitem_DataError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles dgsalesitem.DataError
    MsgBox("Please enter data in correct format", vbInformation, "POS SYSTEM")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all this information from the `e` argument:

```
Private Sub dgsalesitem_DataError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles dgsalesitem.DataError
    Dim curException As Exception = e.Exception
    Dim curCell As DataGridViewCell = dgsalesitem(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
End Sub
```

UPDATE

To highlight the given cell you can just set the `ShowCellErrors` property of the DataGridView to true. Or affect the format of the given cell, for example:

```
curCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow 'Setting the background color of the cell to yello
```

Comment: the code is working fine thank you very much.but i wanted to also highlight the particular cell which is giving error.is there any method for that

Comment: @vimalvasudevan you are welcome. curCell is the current cell, what you want to do with it exactly?

Comment: @vimalvasudevan you have quite a few options. I have updated my answer with a couple of alternatives.